# php array to javascript format?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video.js

I have an array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[title] => Badminton Men's Singles Gold Medal Kashyap Parupalli
[mp4] => http://www.tensports.com/media/video/kashyap.mp4
[webm] => http://www.tensports.com/media/video/kashyap_VP8.webm
[playThumb] => {filedir_2}Kashyap_medal.jpg
[videoPoster] =>{filedir_3}Kashyap_medal.jpg
)

[1] => Array
(
[title] => Boxing Men's Welter (69kg) Silver medal: Mandeep Jangra
[mp4] =>  http://www.tensports.com/media/video/MandeepJangraMedal.mp4
[webm] => http://www.tensports.com/media/video/MandeepJangraMedal_VP8.webm
[playThumb] => {filedir_2}Mandeep_Jangra_medal.jpg
[videoPoster] =>{filedir_3}Mandeep_Jangra_medal.jpg
)

)
```

I am trying to convert it in a object like below.

Javascript Format required :

```
 videos = [
        {
            src : [
                'http://www.tensports.com/media/video/kashyap_VP8.webm',
                'http://www.tensports.com/media/video/kashyap.mp4'
            ],
            poster : '{filedir_2}Kashyap_medal.jpg',
            title : "Badminton Men's Singles Gold Medal Kashyap Parupalli"
        },
        {
            src : [
                'http://www.tensports.com/media/video/MandeepJangraMedal.mp4',
                'http://www.tensports.com/media/video/MandeepJangraMedal_VP8.webm'
            ],
            poster : '{filedir_2}Mandeep_Jangra_medal.jpg',
            title : "Boxing Men's Welter (69kg) Silver medal: Mandeep Jangra"
        }
    ];
```

what I have done :

```
        var videoObject = $.parseJSON(<?php echo $js_VideoURL ?>);//where $js_VideoURL = json_encode($above-array);
        $.each(videoObject, function(key, value) {
            console.log('stuff : ' + key + ", " + value);
        });
```

It's giving me error.I am uncertaing about getting the data in required format.Any help?

Comment: Could you include the error? :)

Comment: @ikanobori http://www.tensports.com/ee/index.php/jayesh-test/commonwealth-games-2014?SDfsd=23432e23

Comment: Add the error message to the question directly so that others can see it and it doesn't disappear when the link becomes stale

Comment: forget the error..basically i am trying to convert a php array to the above js format..

Answer (score 2):

The format you're expecting in javascript is not compatible with the php array you've given.

Going from there I am assuming that is the problem, since you didn't give the exact error message you're encountering. From what I can gather you're missing a piece of PHP to put the video's in the correct format. To solve that you can do the following:

Note the comments in the code, they should explain what is going on.

PHP:

```
// $videos is assumed to be the array you've given in your question
$arr = [];

foreach ($videos as $video) {
    // Create video object
    $obj = new stdClass;

    $obj->src = [
        $video['webm'],
        $video['mp4']
    ];
    $obj->poster = $video['playThumb'];
    $obj->title = $video['title'];

    $arr[] = $obj;
}

// $arr is now the output you would need for processing
```

Javascript:

```
var videoObject = <?php echo $js_VideoURL ?>; //where $js_VideoURL = json_encode($arr);
$.each(videoObject, function(key, value) {
    console.log('stuff : ' + key + ", " + value);
});
```

**Edit:**

Your first mistake is as Quentin mentioned that you're putting the json directly into javascript, which means it will be interpreted as a native javascript object. I missed that in my original answer.

It means you indeed do not need to use `$.parseJSON` to get the object you want. I changed my answer to reflect that.

**Note:**

Your code implies that you have Javascript snippets in your php / html templates. This is considered bad practice, and can be resolved with relative ease.

What you could do is put the json in a data attribute of the relevant html element on the page (escape the json before printing) then picking up the json string using jQuery on initialization with

```
var object = $element.data('json');
```

Using this (jQuery will automatically try parse the string as json) it will be ready for use.

Comment: As a note, you might want to use `console.log('stuff', key, value);` instead, since that allows console to output multiple values in their native format instead of casting them to string first.

Comment: can you check the console,i got the individual data..now i need to push it in the above manner.. http://www.tensports.com/ee/index.php/jayesh-test/commonwealth-games-2014

Answer (score 1):

- The JSON format is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax
- `json_encode` outputs JSON (which, if just dumped in JS, will be treated as a literal)
- `parseJSON` takes a **string** of JSON and converts it to a data structure

Therefore: Don't use `parseJSON` as it will force the object you have into a string (`"[Object object]"`) and then try to parse that as JSON.

Just:

```
var videoObject = <?php echo $js_VideoURL ?>;
```

Comment: @Vagabond — From your URL: `var videoObject = ;`. The PHP code that is supposed to populate `$js_VideoURL` must be wrong.

Comment: i stringified the data and i got the data..from here on what can i do to push the data like javascript above?

Answer (score -2):

Come on.. did you even check PHP docs, or even google json encode!?!?!

```
var videoObject = <?php echo json_encode($js_VideoURL); ?>;
```

Comment: in the question : "where $js_VideoURL = json_encode($above-array)"

Comment: thing is i am not able to convert it in to the required format..I did googled but i am lost in the translation maybe..how a php array can be converted in to some other format